# Boot sequence "hangs"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am unable to boot into Ubuntu. The problem first occurred after upgrading to version 18.04 LTS a couple of years ago.

It looks like this, first I choose Ubuntu in Grub (ver 2.02):

[image: Grub]

The boot sequence starts but always “hangs” after a short while like in the example below:

[image: Boot]

It does not stop exactly on the same place every time, but differs a little on each try.

I have read a lot on the subject but nothing helped and I finally gave up a year ago or so. I would now like to try again to solve the problem but I need help.

A work around would be to setup from start, but then I would loose all my documents. I have managed to access the documents by booting from CD or USB (recently ver 20.04.1), but I am not able to make copies due to access restrictions.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a screen shot of a clean install of 18.04 starting up?

Comment: Hi David, no it is a screen shot of an install of 18.04 upgraded from a previous version. After the upgrade the startup stops/hangs.

Comment: You should still be able to boot with a Live USB and use Nautilus to copy files off your hard drive `/home` directory.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do that but when I try to copy the files it is not possible due to access permission restrictions. I can only look at the files.